# Pin encryption and decryption using des

Tags: encryption

I have one pin-block "A3B5A36ACE23F58A". I want to know what kind of encryption is used to generate this pin block. I was told that DES(Data Encryption Standard) is used but i am not able to get this?

These are the information given to me generate this pin block

PAN :- 1234567890123452
Pin :- 1234
Key :- 0123456789ABCDEF
Clear Component :- C731F2F70EE0D55B
Pin Block :- A3B5A36ACE23F58A

I am very much confused about Clear Component.
What is Clear Component? What is the use of Clear Component in generating pin block?
I asked the queries about Clear Component but i didn't got any relevant answer.

Comment: Probably better asked on the [SO cryptography site](http://crypto.stackexchange.com), this site is about implementation/coding issues.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll ask there.

Comment: Now cross-posted [there](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41510/pin-encryption-using-des)

Answer (score 0):

PinBlock is of different Format ISO 0, ISO 1
ISO 0 - Uses 3DES
ISO 4 - Uses AES Encryption

Clear Pin Block is formed from the Card Number and Pin
Example  Lets say we take a card 6078790000000034 and Pin 1234

```
Step 1. Generate account Number Block [ANB]
         ANB = Last 12 Digits of CardNo ,Discard  Last Digit
         For Card Number 6078790000000034 , ANB will be **879000000003**
Step 2. Format Pin to ISO0 [16 in Length]
        Lets Say  Pin = 1234 
        Pad Logic wiould be 
       Suffix with char “0” + <PinLength> + Actual Pin + 
 <Right Pad with Char “F”   Ex  Padded Pin = **041234FFFFFFFFFF** to make Length to 12 Digits
Step 3. Binary XOR of Step 1 & 2 will yield Clear Pin Block -      **0412B36FFFFFFFFC**
Step 4 - Encrypting the Clear Pin Block with Key [ Usually called ZPK ] or [ Pin Protection Key] Depends where you do the encryption 
 - At the terminal it is called Pin Protection Key
```

Algorithm used is 3DES . Key Size is usually of 32 Hex decimal Digits

Upon Encryption of Clear Pin block with PPK, you get the encrypted Pin Block

> https://groups.google.com/g/jpos-users/c/fdzkQTo94ak